# git equivalent to svn ls -R -v?

Tags: git, svn

I want to calculate the min/max/avg age of files in a repository. For svn I would parse the output of `svn ls -R -v` (or it's xml version `svn ls -R --xml`):

```
(dev) go|w:\srv\lib\dkaddress> svn ls -R -v
  17128 bpwork                Sep 30 13:09 ./
  14691 bpwork             37 Jan 07  2015 .coveragerc
  16918 bphome                Sep 04 19:11 .idea/
  14599 bphome           1058 Dec 19  2014 DEVELOP.rst
  14599 bphome            224 Dec 19  2014 INSTALL.txt
  14010 bpwork              0 Oct 16  2014 README.rst
```

the `-R` option recurses through the repo (first column is the revision of the latest change, 2nd is the author, 3rd the size, 4th is the date of the last revision, and last the relative path). I'm mainly interested in the date and path.

Is there any (simple) way to get this information from git?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is. The simplest I could come up with was this pipeline:

```
git ls-files -z  |
xargs -0 -I'{}' git --no-pager log -1 --format='%h %an %ad {}' -- '{}'
```

The `git ls-files -z` part spits out the files separated by \0, then it goes into `git log` via xargs. The output shows the last commit for the file (`-1` option). The format is %h for the short hash, %an for the author's name, %ad for the author's date and the `{}` part is the file name substitution. Not sure if `--no-pager` is needed but it didn't play well for me without it, showing each line through the pager.

Not the prettiest. Hopefully someone will give you a better answer, but in a pinch it'd do for a script.